# Maximum times without seeing an observation in R

Tags: r, for-loop, counting

I have a vector basically with 100,000 entries consisting on a number from 1 to 6 (I mean, entry one = 4, entry two = 2 and so on). Basically, a 100,000 times sample of a vector containing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

I want to compute the maximum amount of consecutive entries without a value (for example, on these numbers: 1,1,3,4,3,6,6, the maximum amount of times where the 6 doesn't appear is 5, as we have 5 observations that were not a 6 before a 6 appears), and I'm thinking about iterating with a for loop on the vector counting the times the desired value didn't appear, but I'm not sure how to keep it from just counting how many times that value appears. It is something like the opposite of a streak, instead of counting how many times we have a consecutive observation, I want to count how many times we don't have an observation.

I'm basically stuck thinking about the structure of the for loop, and I'm having that gut feel that there's a simpler approach, any ideas?

Comment: While I understand your verbose problem statement it would be a lot easier if you were to provide some reproducible sample code (don't forget to set a fixed random seed when showing random data) and matching expected output. That will help us understand what you are trying to do, and what your expected output should be. Better still, share some of the code you've tried, and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rle` for this---it tells you the number of consecutive values. We'll use the example in your question:

```
x = c(1,1,3,4,3,6,6)
rle(x)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:5] 2 1 1 1 2
#   values : num [1:5] 1 3 4 3 6

## Use it to solve your problem
rx = rle(x != 6)
# This will tell us the number of consecutive TRUE values (x isn't 6)
# and FALSE values (x is 6)
# We want to find the maximum length where the value is TRUE:
max(rx$lengths[rx$values])
# [1] 5
```

You should be able to adapt this to solve your problem. If you have trouble, post an example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm kinda looking to fully understand the code and I just want to clear out a question, rx$lengths will index all the consecutive lengths (in our case, as we only have TRUE and FALSE, it will index the max consecutive trues and the max consecutive falses) and we use rx$values because as they are logical, R will return only the TRUE index. Am I right?:o

Comment: `library(tidyverse)`


`library(ggplot2)`


`x <- 1:6`


`p <- rep(1/6, 6)`


`N <- 1000000`


`set.seed(1)`


`y <- sample(x, N, replace = TRUE, prob = p)`


`ry <- rle(y != 3)`


`Tres_sin_salir <- max(ry$length[ry$values])`

**Sorry about the formatting, didn't managed to make it right

Comment: Your first comment is correct. Your second comment looks good too. (In SO comments you can't do line breaks, so even for R we typically just use semicolons `;` to separate statements.)